# How to fail a test when there are unused mock/stub with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking, stubbing

In Java, using recent versions of Mockito, one expects a test to fail if there are stubs/mocks that were not invoked during the execution of the tests. The exception thrown is shown below:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
```

I was wondering if one could do something similar in Jest? I have searched but couldn't find anything.